# How to Get Numeric ID or Facebook ID from Facebook Profile URL using php without API

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to retrieve facebook Id using facebook profile link without the API. So that the program can retrieve ID of any user just by using that link. I have successfully extracted the username portion of the link but unable to convert it to the numeric id.. Can anyone help me with the next step?

```
function GetUsernameFromFacebookURL($url) {
/**
 * Taken from http://findmyfbid.com/, the valid formats are:
 * https://www.facebook.com/JohnDoe
 * https://m.facebook.com/sally.struthers
 * https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=24353623
 */
$correctURLPattern = '/^https?:\/\/(?:www|m)\.facebook.com\/(?:profile\.php\?id=)?([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)$/';
if (!preg_match($correctURLPattern, $url, $matches)) {
    throw new Exception('Not a valid URL');
}

return $matches[1];
```

}

Comment: Where do you define `$matches` ?